# CV Python WebCam Stream to HTTP

Tags: python, http, opencv, stream, webcam

I have this python WebCam preview code, it doesn't record or any fancy stuff. It is using cv2 library, and I was wondering if it's possible to broadcast/stream via HTTP? If that is the case, this can be set up with raspberry pi later.

```
import time
import os
import sys
import cv2

try:
    def show_webcam(mirror=False):
            cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
            while True:
                    ret_val, img = cam.read()
                    if mirror: 
                            img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
                    cv2.imshow('my webcam', img)
                    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27: 
                            break  # esc to quit
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()

        def main():
                show_webcam(mirror=True)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
            main()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('User Ended Session\n')
    sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. there is an example here [gist source](https://gist.github.com/Tryptich/2a15909e384b582c51b5) .  Python version should available too. In my opinion this approach is hard and will cost you ton of time.

If you just want the simplest solution. Just save your processed image on local disk. Then use and web-server to expose that image file to outside world through http. Finally, make an html page to refresh that image every 0.5 second. This approach is indeed should satisfied all of you need.

Comment: yeah good thinking, I thought of just saving it and having the html page refreshing it every given time. The script can just run in loop and that should do the job for now